Global optima of sigmoid functions
Consider a linear combination of multi-variate sigmoid function $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i \sigma(<a,x> - b_i)$. I would like to know the locations of all local optima.
For the univariate case, I know that for $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i \sigma(x - b_i)$, the sign of its first derivative $f’(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i \sigma(x - b_i)(1 - \sigma(x - b_i))$ would change at most n times, which indicates that all local optima are located in the neighborhood of $x=b_i$. But I don’t know whether this conclusion can be generalized into multivariate case or not.
Thanks.
